# How to execute a function when scroll bar reached bottom in VueJs

Tags: vuejs2

I'am trying to execute a method when scroll bar of the page reached bottom of the page but console is giving an error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.fn is not a function
```

but when i simply try alert() fn it works fine

this is the code i'm trying with

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1azuom2/4/)

Comment: You need an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for the `onscroll`, do this: `window.onscroll = (ev) => { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks sir! you solve the issue.